# Is there a list of the most duplicated questions?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

This is just for fun sake. Would love to see what is the most duplicated question? Some may question the reason behind it? It can be a learning link, where new user can see how two question may sound different but have similar meaning. What type of question not to ask. Further more when you type a question, the tab on top that shows "questions that may already have your answer" is not fool-proof. The best duplicate can be spotted on related question, which is after you have posted. That time either you realize or some one will flag your question.

Comment: By performing a search with the parameters [`is:question duplicate:yes`](http://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+duplicate%3Ayes), you get a list of all the questions closed as duplicates. As far as I know, that's the only way to search for duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The almighty Data Explorer has answers for you: [**Posts that are the target of the most duplicate closures**](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/265721/posts-that-are-the-target-of-the-most-duplicate-closures).

As of this writing, only the following questions are the target of more than one duplicate closure:

- [What's the difference between the FMA and FMA Brotherhood series?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/55/whats-the-difference-between-the-fma-and-fma-brotherhood-series)
- [How did Nagato gain his Rinnegan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-did-nagato-gain-his-rinnegan)
- [What happens when Naruto is talking to the Kyuubi?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/664/what-happens-when-naruto-is-talking-to-the-kyuubi)
- [How are Chaos;Head, Steins;Gate, and Robotics;Notes connected?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/how-are-chaoshead-and-steinsgate-connected)

(Since this is a small site, the results are obviously sparse and not very interesting. A site like Stack Overflow has [much more interesting results](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/265721/posts-that-are-the-target-of-the-most-duplicate-closures).)